# About the convergence of the complex series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm struggling to show that the series 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k(k+z)}$$
converges for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{-1,-2,\cdots\}$. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%281%2F%28k%28k%2Bz%29%29,k%3D1,inf%29) says it indeed does converge, but I have no idea how or what to do with finding a nice comparison to the terms $\left | \frac{1}{k(k+z)} \right |=\frac{1}{k|k+z|}$, where $|z|\neq -k$.

Comment: Observe that k*|k+z|=k^2*|1 + z/k|>k^2 * (1-e), for sufficiently large k.

Comment: @tetsuzan Why is $|1+z/k|>1- e$, for large $k$?

Comment: Because |1+z/k| approaches 1 as k goes to infinity. In particular, by definition of limit, it gets greater than 1-e>0.

Comment: Here e stands for epsilon, not the constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the minimum of $\lvert k(k+z)\rvert$ is positive, we know
$$\biggl\lvert \frac1{k(k+z)}\biggr\rvert\sim_\infty\frac 1{k^2},$$
hence it is normally convergent.

Comment: I am not familiar with this notation, $\sim_{\infty}$. What is it? Taylor expansion at $0$?

Comment: It is *equivalence* of functions (of $k$) at infinity, as defined in asymptotic analysis. Roughly, it means the ratio tends to $1$ at infinity, and it is known two series with positive terms equivalent at infinity both converge or both diverge.

Comment: (Edited) Could you please elaborate what tetzusan commented? I am just trying to learn more. My understanding is, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $N>0$ such that $|(1+\frac{z}{k})-1|=|\frac{z}{k}|<\epsilon$, for all $k\geq N$. If $1-\epsilon > 0$, then $1-\epsilon < 1-|\frac{z}{k}| \leq |1+\frac{z}{k}|$, that is $|1+\frac{z}{k}|>1-\epsilon$, for all $k\geq N$. Then $\frac{1}{|k^2(1+\frac{z}{k})|}<\frac{1}{k^2(1-\epsilon)}$ for all $k\geq N$, and the series $\sum_{k=N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2(1-\epsilon)}$ converges absolutely.